# Level sets of a function using "min"

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, min

**UPDATE**

To summarize my initial post below, I have difficulties plotting level sets of functions involving 'min' such as the following function :

```
def f(x,y):
   return min(x,x-y,x**2,y+1)
```

Code I'm using to plot level sets is :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.ion()
x_ = np.linspace(-180,180,num=40)
y_ = np.linspace(-180,180,num=40)
x,y = np.meshgrid(x_,y_)
levels = f(x,y)
c = plt.contour(x,y,levels,50)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

which works fine for a function involving regular arithmetic operations (+,-,**,*,/). Using function `f`, I have this error :

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

pointing at the return line of `f`. 
How can I plot the level sets of my function `f` ?

---

**INITIAL POST**

I'm trying to plot level sets of two functions f1 and f2 defined as follows :

```
A = -73.95, 48.73
L=180


######## f1
def distance(a,b):
      """ a and b tuples """
      return np.sqrt((a[0]-b[0])**2+(a[1]-b[1])**2)

def f1(x,y):
       """ simple distance """
       p = x,y
       #print p
       return distance(p,A)

######## f2
def images(p):
        """ p tuple """
        #print "len(p) in images : "+str(len(p))+"\n"
        #print p
        pHC = (p[0],p[1]+L)
        pHR = (p[0]+L,p[1]+L)
        pHL = (p[0]-L,p[1]+L)
        pCR = (p[0]+L,p[1])
        pCL = (p[0]-L,p[1])
        pDC = (p[0],p[1]-L)
        pDR = (p[0]+L,p[1]-L)
        pDL = (p[0]-L,p[1]-L)
        return pHC,pHR,pHL,pCR,pCL,pDC,pDR,pDL
def minD(p,focal):
        """
        distance with images (p and focal are tuples)
        """
        #print p
        pHC,pHR,pHL,pCR,pCL,pDC,pDR,pDL = images(p)
        dHC = distance(focal,pHC)
        dHR = distance(focal,pHR)
        dHL = distance(focal,pHL)
        dCR = distance(focal,pCR)
        dCL = distance(focal,pCL)
        dDC = distance(focal,pDC)
        dDR = distance(focal,pDR)
        #print "len(dHC) : "+str(len(dHC))
        #print "len(dHC[0]) : "+str(len(dHC[0]))
        #print dHC
        d = min([dHC,dHR,dHL,dCR,dCL,dDC,dDR,dDL,distance(p,focal)])
        return d

def f2(phi,psi):
       p = phi,psi
       return minD(p,A)
```

Here's my code for plotting level sets :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.ion()
x_ = np.linspace(-180,180,num=40)
y_ = np.linspace(-180,180,num=40)
x,y = np.meshgrid(x_,y_)
levels1 = f1(x,y)
#levels2 = f2(x,y)
c = plt.contour(x,y,levels,50)
#c = plt.contour(x,y,levels2,50)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

My plot seems to be correct with the function `f1` (at least there's no code errors). However, with function `f2`, I have an error at the line before the last of `minD` :

```
    d = min([dHC,dHR,dHL,dCR,dCL,dDC,dDR,dDL,distance(p,focal)])
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

With some prints, I could find that the elements of the list on which I perform the min (in `minD` function) are arrays in the case of `f2` and not single elements as for `f1`. 
How can I plot level sets of function f2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to call the numpy version of min, not python's version which is expecting numbers as an input and gives you the minimum of them--this is where the ValueError comes from.  There are two version in numpy; *np.min* and *np.minimum*.  *np.min* will give you the minimum value of an array (so a number) and *np.minimum* will do a point-wise minimum of the array (so another array).  You want the latter.

Unfortunately, I don't think you can simply do *np.minimum(array1, array2, array3)* like to have above, so I think you need to nest the *np.minimum* calls.  Though if will do this often, I think you can create a function that will nest these calls for you to make it easier to read.  This is what I got and it seems to work:

```
def f(x,y):
    return np.minimum(np.minimum(np.minimum(x,x-y),x**2),y+1)

plt.figure()

x_ = np.linspace(-180, 180, num=200)
y_ = np.linspace(-180, 180, num=200)
x,y = np.meshgrid(x_, y_)

levels = f(x, y)

c = plt.contour(x, y, levels, 50)
plt.colorbar()
```

This yields:

[image]

(note, I increased num from 40 to 200 to help matplotlib with the non-smooth parts)

Comment: I didn't know about `np.minimum`. I tried out `np.min` only and of course I had same error. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: For those who'd like to know how to nest `np.minimum` automatically, use `reduce(np.minimum,[x,x-y,x**2,y+1])`

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I'm going straightforward and not using the `meshgrid` function of `numpy` :

```
x=np.linspace(-180,180,num=40)
y=np.linspace(-180,180,num=40)
levels=np.zeros((len(x),len(y)))
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(y)):
        levels[i,j]=f2(x[i],y[j])
plt.contour(x,y,levels.T)
```

This is not optimal in time as it is the case with `meshgrid` function, but I'd rather use this than understand what is going on with my data in `meshgrid`. I have no time for this unfortunately.

Output : 
[image]

Comment: So you want to know what is going on with your data in `meshgrid`? Let me try to explain how it works.  
In the 2D case it will repeat the first array row-wise and the second one column-wise so in the end both have the same shape `(len(x), len(y))`. If you then broadcast them (you can also imagine putting them on top of each other) you will get every combination of x,y pairs. This is extremely redundant but since the data is nicely aligned for vectorized computation it will give you a neat speedup.